# Getting "*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated Aborted" after calling recvfrom( ) function for UDP communication

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, serversocket, udpclient

I am facing an error whenever I call a `recvfrom()` function for UDP in server side:

> buffer overflow detected ***: terminated  Aborted

What is the meaning of this error? I am not able to understand.

```cpp
unsigned int len;
int rv,i;
int tmp;
//char msg[200],command=0;
unsigned short *Fptr;
float Float_Temp;
//make socket blocking
FD_ZERO(&readnbs);
FD_SET(g_iUDP_datalogger_soc, &readnbs);
g_UDP_Blocktimervalue.tv_sec = 0;
g_UDP_Blocktimervalue.tv_usec = UDP_REC_BLOCKTIME;
rv = select(g_iUDP_datalogger_soc + 1, &readnbs, NULL, NULL, &g_UDP_Blocktimervalue);

len = sizeof(g_UDP_ClientAddr);

if (rv == 1) {

    printf(" \n\n\n\n\n rv=%d\n\n\n\n",rv);
    tmp = recvfrom(g_iUDP_datalogger_soc, &tmp, SIZE_UDP_MSG, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &g_UDP_ClientAddr, &len);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = recvfrom(g_iUDP_datalogger_soc, [YOUR BUFFER ?] , SIZE_UDP_MSG, 0,(struct sockaddr *)...
```

You're trying to buffer the received data into a single `int` (tmp) object, which you are also using as the return value from the `recvfrom()`, and even not checking in any way - either for error, nor for received data.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking `recvfrom()` to read `SIZE_UDP_MSG` number of bytes into `tmp`, which is an `int`.  You did not show what `SIZE_UDP_MSG` is defined as, but if `SIZE_UDP_MSG > sizeof(int)`, you are going to be writing bytes past the bounds of `tmp` into surrounding memory, corrupting the memory.  That is a buffer overflow.

Perhaps you meant to receive the bytes into your (commented out) `msg` buffer instead?

```cpp
char msg[SIZE_UDP_MSG];
tmp = recvfrom(..., msg, SIZE_UDP_MSG, ...);
```